# pynock: unable to convert a graph partition into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the example below, where I am trying to create a small one-partition graph and export it to a `pandas` dataframe:

```py
from pynock import Edge, Node, Partition

# create a new partition
p = Partition(part_id=1)

# add nodes to the partition
for k in range(3):
    # create a node with an edge hardcoded to link to node 1
    _node = Node(node_id=k, name=f"{k}")
    _edge = Edge(node_id=1)
    _node.add_edge(_edge)

    # add the node to the partition
    p.add_node(_node)

# convert to dataframe
p.to_df()
# will print an empty dataframe
```

When I inspect the partition with `print(p)` I can see that the nodes are added to the partition. Why is the dataframe empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to adding the nodes to the partition, the partition node names should be created using `p.create_node_name(...)`:

```py
from pynock import Edge, Node, Partition

# create a new partition
p = Partition(part_id=1)

# add nodes to the partition
for k in range(3):
    # create a node with an edge hardcoded to link to node 1
    _node = Node(node_id=k, name=f"node_{k}")
    _edge = Edge(node_id=1)
    _node.add_edge(_edge)

    # add the node to the partition
    p.create_node_name(k)
    p.add_node(_node)

# convert to dataframe
p.to_df()
```